# Screen freezes when installing Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: nvidia, laptop, asus

When I boot Ubuntu GNOME on my PC, the loading icon appears and automatically freezes after 15 seconds. I wonder if there is a problem with my graphics card.

Model: Asus
CPU: Core i7
Graphics card: Nvvidia GeForce GTX 950M

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ubuntu GNOME are you running?

Under 17.04, I was able to resolve my display problem with a kernel flag, `acpi_rev_override=5`, details here: [Install ubuntu 17.04 on dell xps 15 9560](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925188/install-ubuntu-17-04-on-dell-xps-15-9560/927814#927814)

However, to aid in trouble-shooting boot issues, you'll want to also remove the `splash` and `quiet` flags, as it'll be easier to see error messages as they get displayed during boot.

For details on editing your `grub` file, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2. Remember to run `sudo update-grub` whenever you make changes to `grub`.

Rich